# New Learner - Need Help in prasing nested json in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get a particular value from nested JSON

JSON is as below

```
    {
    "ListOn": true,
    "currentList": "Counter_Master",
    "deployedList": [
        {
            "name": "Master",
            "skipForSchedule": false,
            "Type": "regular"
        },
        {
            "plType": "regular",
            "skipForSchedule": false,
            "name": "Name_test"
        }
    ],
    "uptime": 1216.819
}
```

This is what I did till now

```
import json
 with open('config.json') as f:
            #print("file is open")
            data = json.load(f)

curr_list = data['deployedPlaylists'] [1] . values()
curr_list = curr_playlist[1]
print("we are finding the name of curr_list[1]", curr_list)
```

I am not able to pickup 2nd name which is "Name_test" in deployedList[1].name

from shell, I can do with below command, want to do in python, but as I am new to python could not find the exact way.

```
sudo jq -r '.deployedlists[1].name' _config.json
```

Requesting for help.
Thanks

Comment: `true` and `false` is not a valid boolean in python. it should be `True` and `False`. And what you need to do is `data['deployedPlaylists'] [1]["name"]`

Comment: I do not have control over the JSON, so most of the time I get an error - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by `don't control over json`. You should at least know the structure of the json. If you know the structure then you can get that element with proper indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have typos in your code

Just fix `data['deployedPlaylists'] [1] . values()` to be `data['deployedList'] [1]['name']` which will be storing the value `Name_test` as required.

just take in mind that `json.read()` returns the value of the json file in python dictionary so to manipulate the values of the json file read more about python dictionaries how they are stored and how to access their values.

Comment: Thanks data['deployedList'] [1]['name']  this is what I was looking for...